# Shellscript evaluate command vs command difference: multiple $(uuidgen) get me same result

Tags: shell

`uuidgen` is suppose to generate a random uuid for every call. thinking below command:

```
╰─○ cat a.txt | xargs -I {} -L 1 sh -c "uuidgen"
54693322-1ABF-4FCB-96E5-90EC0F4AC33E
9F1BA4CF-5612-46D7-90E9-EE653F0396FE
25F5D853-03BA-42F7-9FF8-1D3E124D09B3
046A348E-3FC0-414A-8469-21A016147245
```

This is Good, but below command will give me same uuids:

```
╰─○ cat a.txt | xargs -I {} -L 1 sh -c "echo $(uuidgen)"
7477A621-331C-4727-8471-677528BC79AC
7477A621-331C-4727-8471-677528BC79AC
7477A621-331C-4727-8471-677528BC79AC
7477A621-331C-4727-8471-677528BC79AC
```

Comment: This is expected. Are you asking "why that happens"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command substitution `$(..)` inside double quotes `"` is expanded *before* the command is run by the shell. So you are running:

```
xargs -I {} -L 1 sh -c "echo 7477A621-331C-4727-8471-677528BC79AC"
```

and it will print same value each time. Debug script with `set -x`. See `xargs -t` output. Check your scripts with shellcheck.net .

If you want to pass the string `echo $(uuidgen)` as-is to the shell spawned by `xargs` you have to quote it.

```
xargs sh -c "echo \$(uuidgen)"
# or
xargs sh -c 'echo $(uuidgen)'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the tips for debugging, helped me a lot!